# JDBC Filter blocks all Servlets & URL Patterns but not direct access to files themselves

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, filter

I followed a [tutorial](https://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc#a827434) online and there were some mistakes here and there but I understood the ideas behind it and the mindset. I have a school project on developing a Web App and I decided to do it in Java EE (since I was comfortable with Java).

My source code consists of 5 packages (Beans, Connection, Filter, Servlets and Utilities).

The problem consists of the JDBC Filter, as told in the title. It checks that everywhere on the website, I'm still connected to the MySQL Database. However, whenever it goes on anything of a localhost:8080/*, an SQL Exception is enabled, complaining about the [Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRhI2.png). Except this error doesn't arrive when opening files directly in the path, instead of using URL Patterns.

So I decided to do some investigating. Checked the console and climbed up the errors. It complained about the `ConnectionUtils` class, specifically the `getMySQLConnection` method, which comes from the `MySQLConnUtils` class.

The problem is that when I try the method itself in the `main`method, it [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM7zn.png) !

```
package Connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class ConnectionUtils {
public static Connection getMyConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    return MySQLConnUtils.getMySQLConnection();
}
public static void closeQuietly(Connection conn)
{
    try{
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
public static void rollbackQuietly(Connection conn){
    try{
        conn.rollback();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Get connection...");
    Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getMyConnection();
    System.out.println("Get connection " + conn);
    System.out.println("Done!");
  }
}
```

```
package Connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySQLConnUtils {
    public static Connection getMySQLConnection() throws SQLException{
        String userName = "username";
        String password="pwd";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("CLASS NOT FOUND");
        }
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flytogo";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,userName,password);
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Here's the filter proving that the url-pattern it applies to is "/*" :

```
package Filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import Connection.ConnectionUtils;
import Utils.MyUtils;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


@WebFilter(filterName = "jdbcFilter", urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class JDBCFilter implements Filter {

    public JDBCFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    // Check the target of the request is a servlet?
    private boolean needJDBC(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("JDBC Filter");
        //
        // Servlet Url-pattern: /spath/*
        //
        // => /spath
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
        // => /abc/mnp
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();

        String urlPattern = servletPath;

        if (pathInfo != null) {
            // => /spath/*
            urlPattern = servletPath + "/*";
        }

        // Key: servletName.
        // Value: ServletRegistration
        Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> servletRegistrations = request.getServletContext()
                .getServletRegistrations();

        // Collection of all servlet in your Webapp.
        Collection<? extends ServletRegistration> values = servletRegistrations.values();
        for (ServletRegistration sr : values) {
            Collection<String> mappings = sr.getMappings();
            if (mappings.contains(urlPattern)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        // Only open connections for the special requests.
        // (For example, the path to the servlet, JSP, ..)
        //
        // Avoid open connection for commons request.
        // (For example: image, css, javascript,... )
        //
        if (this.needJDBC(req)) {

            System.out.println("Open Connection for: " + req.getServletPath());

            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                // Create a Connection.
                conn = ConnectionUtils.getMyConnection();
                // Set outo commit to false.
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);


                // Store Connection object in attribute of request.
                MyUtils.storeConnection(request, conn);

                // Allow request to go forward
                // (Go to the next filter or target)
                chain.doFilter(request, response);

                // Invoke the commit() method to complete the transaction with the DB.
                conn.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ConnectionUtils.rollbackQuietly(conn);
                throw new ServletException();
            } finally {
                ConnectionUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
            }
        }
        // With commons requests (images, css, html, ..)
        // No need to open the connection.
        else {
            // Allow request to go forward
            // (Go to the next filter or target)
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

Anyways, thanks in advance to anyone who would know what could be the source of mistakes or error.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace of the error you're getting as **text**. In any case, the most likely cause is that you don't have the driver on the classpath.

Comment: Please before it's too late for your project, throw away that tutorial and follow the normal practice of letting your server manage the connections, or using a normal Java EE server with JPA built-in.

Comment: @BalusC, I don't understand. Tomcat is the server that I'm using. How am I interfering with the connections?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yet when I use the main() method in the said class, it's working. Truly it's weird that it works there and not elsewhere.

Comment: @FaresKissoum Classpaths in web applications are different from claspaths in simple applications run through `main`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How do I know what's the classpath for my web app? I added the mysql connector as an external library.

Comment: You either need to include it in the main classpath of your webserver (eg for tomcat, in its `lib` folder, or in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your WAR.